# How to use scrollPosition(id:) to get index of item in ScrollView in iOS 17

Tags: ios, swiftui, scrollview

One of the new ScrollView modifiers introduced for iOS 17 was `.scrollPosition(id:)`, which allows us to bind the ID of the scrolled-to view. From Apple's documentation, we can do:

```
@Binding var items: [Item]
@Binding var scrollPosition: Item.ID?


ScrollView {
    LazyVStack {
        ForEach(items) { item in
            ItemView(item)
        }
    }
    .scrollTargetLayout()
}
.scrollPosition(id: $scrollPosition)
```

But let's say we'd like to have `scrollPosition` represent the *index* of each `item` in `items`. For example, when we're scrolled to the first `ItemView`, `scrollPosition` should be 0; when we scroll to the second `ItemView`, it should be 1, and so on.

How can we achieve this in SwiftUI (with this modifier)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this approach, declare `scrollPosition: Int?`,
use an `items.enumerated()` in the `ForEach` loop, and an `id(index)`, such as:

```
  @Binding var scrollPosition: Int?
```

and

```
  ForEach(Array(items.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { index, item in
      ItemView(item).id(index)
  }
```

EDIT-1:

Here is my answer complete test code that shows how to use `.scrollPosition(id:...)` when
`....scrollPosition represent the index of each item`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items = [MyItem(name: "item-0"), MyItem(name: "item-1"), MyItem(name: "item-2"),
                        MyItem(name: "item-3"), MyItem(name: "item-4"), MyItem(name: "item-5"),
                        MyItem(name: "item-6"), MyItem(name: "item-7"), MyItem(name: "item-8")]
    
    @State var scrollPosition: Int?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(scrollPosition ?? 0)")
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(Array(items.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { index, item in
                        ItemView(item: item).id(index)
                    }
                }
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .scrollPosition(id: $scrollPosition)
        }
    }
}

struct ItemView: View {
    var item: MyItem

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.green.gradient)
                .frame(height: 333)
            Text(item.name)
        }
    }
}

struct MyItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
}
```

Comment: This solution works - although it took me a while to figure out that this only works with a `LazyVStack`, do you know why that is?

Comment: sorry, no idea.